# difference between sanitize and strip_tags rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper

Exactly I don't know the difference between these. 
I read this

`http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html`

but don't get the exact difference.
Could anyone let me know the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sanitize you can allow some HTML tags or class, strip_tags cannot. It does the same thing. Check the code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/76a0b1028e312b6c3c00a50b4a09d68c23b5e713/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb#L80

Comment: That means strip_tags will remove every thing?
And in `sanitize` having a provision to restrict.

Answer (score 6):

`sanitize` is using a white list sanitizer.  `strip_tags` strips all tags.

Compare:

```
[64] pry(main)> sanitize "hello <h1>h1</h1> <b>b</b>"
=> "hello <h1>h1</h1> <b>b</b>"
[65] pry(main)> strip_tags "hello <h1>h1</h1> <b>b</b>"
=> "hello h1 b"
```

If you don't supply any whitelisted tags, `sanitize` allows the following tags by default.

```
[66] pry(main)> ActionView::Base.white_list_sanitizer.allowed_tags.to_a * ', '
=> "strong, em, b, i, p, code, pre, tt, samp, kbd, var, sub, sup,
dfn, cite, big, small, address, hr, br, div, span, h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, abbr, acronym, a, img,
blockquote, del, ins"
```

If you supply your own whitelisted tags, then they override the default ones.

```
[67] pry(main)> sanitize "hello <h1>h1</h1> <b>b</b>", tags: %w(b)
=> "hello h1 <b>b</b>"
```

Another distinction between `sanitize` and `strip_tags` is that `sanitize` removes the content (the stuff in between) of some tags, notably the `<script>` tag.

Compare:

```
[68] pry(main)> sanitize "a<script>alet('foo')</script>"
=> "a"
[69] pry(main)> strip_tags "a<script>alet('foo')</script>"
=> "aalet('foo')"
```

Also, `sanitize` does html-escape for some characters, but `strip_tags` doesn't.

```
[70] pry(main)> sanitize "< &"
=> "&lt; &"
[71] pry(main)> strip_tags "< &"
=> "< &"
```

In addition, they handle nested tags differently.  Compare the following,

```
[73] pry(main)> sanitize "some<<b>script>alert('hello')<</b>/script>", tags: []
=> "some&lt;script>alert('hello')&lt;/script>"
[74] pry(main)> strip_tags "some<<b>script>alert('hello')<</b>/script>"
=> "somealert('hello')"
```